# What would be Optimized Query for the given?

Tags: sql

```
**How to optimize this Query??**
------------------------------
```

Basically I have three tables and wanted to extract the data common in two but not in third one. But also the data which are common in three should also be in the result.

```
select A.A_Name from A
inner join C on A.A_Name=C.C_Name
union 
select b.B_Name from B
inner join C on B.B_Name=C.C_Name
union 
select a.A_Name from A
inner join b on A.A_Name=b.B_Name
except 
(
select A.A_Name from A
inner join B on A.A_Name=B.B_Name
except 
select A.A_Name from A
inner join B on A.A_Name=B.B_Name
inner join C on B.B_Name=C.C_Name
)
```

[Click here to get an idea what I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7m5Pl.jpg)

Comment: What type of database are you using?  Optimization is handled differently depending on what type you are using.  Also when trying to optimize a query the explain plan is probably the most helpful piece of information.  A simple internet search should tell you how to get the explain plan for your database.

Comment: How is that picture not just the intersection of A and C?   What table is the third?

Comment: Your picture and your words contain contradictions.  `data common in two but not in third one` and yet also `common in three should also be in the result` - if a datum is present in all three it shouldn't be included according to the first rule, but should be included according to the second rule?

Comment: Or do you mean `any data that is present in any combination of two or three tables`?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you example from SQL Server. Table C has no use in this, and A n B gives us the drawed section. thus,

```
SELECT * FROM A
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM B
```

gives you correct soluton.

Please note that since I dont know your data types. I simply assumed that they are same.